# how to implement decorators for a recursive function in a class

Tags: python, recursion, decorator

I am writing a class that takes input list of integers at initialization. The class has bunch of sorting methods. i wanted to add a decorator which would shuffle the input list before every method call. When trying to implement a recursive bubble sort, the decorator causes `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

I tried to pass the self argument so the decorator can access the class variable. However i need help on how to let the recursive function work with decorator

```py
import functools
from searching import timer
import random


def shuffle(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        random.shuffle(self.ip_list)
        value = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return value
    return wrapper


class sorting:
    def __init__(self, ip_list):
        self.ip_list = ip_list
        self.n = len(self.ip_list)
        self.timer_dict = {}

    @shuffle
    @timer
    def recursive_bubble_sort(self):
        print(self.ip_list)
        for j in range(self.n):
            try:
                if self.ip_list[j] > self.ip_list[j+1]:
                    self.ip_list[j], self.ip_list[j + 1] = self.ip_list[j + 1], self.ip_list[j]
                    self.recursive_bubble_sort()
            except IndexError:
                pass
        print(self.ip_list)


x = [i for i in range(0,30)]
s = sorting(x)
s.recursive_bubble_sort()
```

Comment: Why are you using a decorator for this, and why are you using bubble sort is my second question?

Comment: Just learning them and trying to help improve myself

Comment: I would look into learning merge sort. Bubble sort is often taught because it is easy to implement but extremely ineffective (O(n^2), I am unsure why they even teach it). That being said I'll see if I can debug it.

Comment: Your sort won't work without passing anything to it. Recursive functions work by passing a subset to a recursive call. You are trying to do it all in place which is causing logical issues.

Comment: yes, i am making a class of all the sorting methods, so lets a merge sort could be my next method in this class, i want the decorator to shuffle the class variable `self.ip_list` before the method gets executed

Answer (score 5):

It's a very bad idea to decorate a recursive method like the one in your example. For some methods and decorators it could work, but not a sorting algorithm. The issue is that every recursive call is going to end up calling through the decorator's wrapper. With your `shuffle` decorator, that means you're going to reshuffle the list on every recursive call, which is why your list is never getting sorted. Even if the sort didn't get reshuffled on every call, your `timer` decorator would probably have a similar issue, as it would be trying to time every recursive call, not just the top level call to the function.

One option might be to keep the recursive method and the decorated method separate. This is often a good way to design an API for a function that's going to be implemented with recursion anyway, as you will often need to pass extra arguments into the recursive calls, but the top level call doesn't need them.

```
@shuffle
@timer
def bubble_sort_recursive(self):        # despite the name, this function is not recursive itself
    self.bubble_sort_recursive_helper()

def bubble_sort_recursive_helper(self): # all the recursion happens in this helper method
    ... # recursive code goes here, recursive calls should be to the helper!
```

Comment: you are right it is timing for every recursive call